# Spivak, Ch. 18, Problem *40: Prove that if $f(x)=e^{-1/x^2}$ for $x\neq 0$, and $f(0)=0$, then $f^{(k)}(0)=0$ for all $k$.

Tags: calculus, limits, solution-verification, logarithms, exponential-function

There is a type of problem that comes up sometimes in Spivak's *Calculus* that is probably my least favorite type of problem in the book. This type of problem involves proving something about the k-th derivative of a function, by making a conjecture about the terms contained in that k-th derivative and then proving it with induction.

Here is one such problem

> *40. Prove that if $f(x)=e^{-1/x^2}$ for $x\neq 0$, and $f(0)=0$, then $f^{(k)}(0)=0$ for all $k$ (you will encounter the same sort of
> difficulties as in Problem 10-21). Hint: Consider functions
> $g(x)=e^{-1/x^2}P(1/x)$ for a polynomial function $P$.

By the way, Problem 10-21 is the same sort of problem

> *10-21. Prove that if $f^{(n)}(g(a))$ and $g^{(n)}(a)$ both exist, then $(f\circ g)^{(n)}(a)$ exists.

**Here is the solution manual solution to problem 40**

> The formulas for $f'(x)$ and $f''(x)$ for $x\neq 0$ given in the text
> suggest the following conjecture, which is easy to prove by induction
> on $k$
>
> $$f^{(k)}(x)=e^{-1/x^2}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{3k} \frac{a_i}{x^i}\tag{1}$$
>
> for some numbers $a_1,...,a_{3k}$.
>
> It is then clear that $f^{(k)}(0)=0$ for all $k$ using the same
> argument as in the text.

I came up with a solution that used two proofs by induction. The first induction to prove

$$\forall n, n\in\mathbb{N}\implies f^{(n)}(x)=e^{-1/x^2}\cdot P(1/x), \text{ with } P \text{ polynomial}$$

and the second induction that uses the result from the first to prove

$$\forall n, n\in\mathbb{N}\implies f^{(n)}(0)=0$$

I think that this solution is actually the same as the solution manual, only longer because I didn't go ahead and sub in for $P(1/x)$ in the first induction.

**Here is my attempted proof**

Let $A=\{ n:n\in\mathbb{N} \land f^{(n)}(x)=e^{-1/x^2}\cdot P(1/x), \text{ with } P \text{ polynomial} \}$. Let's prove that $A=\mathbb{N}$ using induction.

If $n=1$ then

$$f'(x)=\frac{2}{x^3}e^{-1/x^2}=P(1/x)\cdot e^{-1/x^2}\tag{2}$$

where $P(x)=2x^3$.

Assume that $k\in A$, ie that $$f^{(k)}(x)=e^{-1/x^2}\cdot P(1/x)$$ for some polynomial $P$.

Then

$$f^{(k+1)}(x)=e^{-1/x^2}\frac{2}{x^3}\cdot P(1/x)+e^{-1/x^2}P'(1/x)\cdot \frac{(-1)}{x^2}\tag{3}$$

$$=e^{-1/x^2}\left [ \frac{2P(1/x)}{x^3}-\frac{P'(1/x)}{x^2} \right ]\tag{4}$$

Now, if $P$ is a polynomial then

$$P(x)=\sum\limits_{i=0}^n a_ix^i\tag{5}$$

$$P(1/x)=\sum\limits_{i=0}^n \frac{a_i}{x^i}\tag{6}$$

and so

$$\frac{P(1/x)}{x^3}=\sum\limits_{i=0}^n \frac{a_i}{x^{i+3}}=Q_1(1/x)\tag{7}$$

Thus $Q_1$ is a polynomial.

In a very similar way, I believe we can show that if

$$Q_2(x)=\frac{P'(1/x)}{x^2}$$

then $Q_2$ is a polynomial. Thus, if

$$R(1/x)=\frac{2P(1/x)}{x^3}-\frac{P'(1/x)}{x^2}$$

Then $R$ is a polynomial and therefore, from $(3)$ and $(4)$ we have that

$$f^{(k+1)}(x)=e^{-1/x^2}\cdot R(1/x)$$

where $R$ is a polynomial.

Therefore, by induction $A=\mathbb{N}$.

**Now let's do a second induction to prove the result we really want.**

Let $$B=\{ n:n\in\mathbb{N} \land f^{(n)}(0)=0 \}$$

If $n=1$ then

$$f'(0)=\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \frac{e^{-1/x^2}}{x}=0$$

therefore $n\in B$.

Now assume that $k\in B$, ie $f^{(k)}(0)=0$.

Since from the first induction result we know that

$$f^{(k)}(x)=e^{-1/x^2}\cdot P(1/x)$$

then

$$f^{(k+1)}(x)=\lim\limits_{h\to 0} \frac{f^{(k)}(h)-f^{(k)}(0)}{h}$$

$$=\lim\limits_{h\to 0} \frac{f^{(k)}(h)}{h}$$

$$=\lim\limits_{h\to 0} \frac{e^{-1/h^2}\cdot P(1/h)}{h}$$

$$=\lim\limits_{h\to \infty} \frac{h\cdot P(h)}{e^{h^2}}$$

$$=0$$

The last step is justified by the following theorem

> Ch. 18, Theorem 6: $n\in\mathbb{N}\implies
> > \lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{e^x}{x^n}=\infty$

Therefore, $B=\mathbb{N}$, which is the desired result.

$$\blacksquare$$

Is this proof correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct